# The use of self.current_user in ruby on rails tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to understand this piece of code

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end
end
```

Using the line

```
self.current_user = user
```

will it create a variable named current_user for the class SessionsController (the above module belongs to SessionsController class)?

If  I use

```
@current_user = user
```

instead of the above line, the code seems to work the exact same way. How?!

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`self.current_user = user` just call the method `current_user=(user)`, and the method only does `@current_user = user`, so it just work the same if you do `@current_user = user`.

Comment: They're equivalent in this case, but just wanted to note that if there was any additional logic in current_user=() then just setting @current_user = user in the sign_in() method would bypass it.

Comment: Could you clarify what class is `self` referring to? Module `SessionsHelper` is included in `ApplicationHelper`, so I'm not sure if `self` still refers to the same thing when used in different controllers?

Answer (score 0):

`self.current_user = user`, this expression is to indicate `current_user` is the method in class `Sessions` (mixin by module `SessionsHelper`) rather than a local variable. The self there represent the class `Sessions`, so this line is just a method invoking, the same effect with `@current_user = user` or `current_user=(user)`.