# Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl, Chapter 8, "Current User" section

Tags: railstutorial.org

I'm new to Rails and have been going through the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. Up until this point, I've been able to understand everything in the tutorial but now I think I'm stuck midway through Chapter 8. I'd like some confirmation from more experienced Rails programmers, that I'm following the author's explanation correctly. I'm talking specifically about [Chapter 8, Section 8.2.3](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-current_user) below:

In Section 8.2.3, the "sign_in" method has the line:

```
self.current_user = user
```

So by using "self" instead of just "current_user", current_user has been made part of the Session, but not yet stored in the database, correct?

If that's the case, the methods listed in [Listing 8.22](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#code-current_user_working) are getter and setter methods, correct? The first to store current_user in the DB, and the second to retrieve it as needed?

And finally, the getter and setter methods are needed because its bad practice to expose an instance variable in a method (in this case "sign_in")? In other words, it would be bad to replace:

```
self.current_user = user
```

with

```
@current_user = user
```

in the "sign_in" method?

I appreciate any help and advice.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I am not highly proficient in Rails, but here is my layman's understanding of the methods in `SessionsHelper`.

Firstly, `@current_user` is an instance variable of module `SessionsHelper`. This means that it *persists* for subsequent calls of the methods in `SessionsHelper`.

---

```rb
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end
```

> **So by using "self" instead of just "current_user", current_user has been made part of the Session, but not yet stored in the database, correct?**

`self.current_user = user` does **not** make 'current_user' a part of anything.
`self` refers to itself, *SessionsHelper*.
`self.current_user =` effectively calls its **own** method, the setter method, `def current_user=(user)`.

---

> **If that's the case, the methods listed in Listing 8.22 are getter and
>   setter methods, correct?**

Yes.

```rb
  def current_user=(user) # Setter.
    @current_user = user
  end
```

> **The first to store current_user in the DB,**

No. The first method, `current_user=`, does **not** store anything into the database. All it does is set the instance variable `@current_user` to `user`.

---

```rb
  def current_user # Getter.
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end
```

> **and the second to retrieve it as needed?**

The second method, `current_user`, returns an **existing** `@current_user` value.
If `@current_user` is **`nil`**(null), it runs

```rb
||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
```

which retrieves and sets `@current_user` as the `User` from the database based on the browser's *remember_token* cookie.

---

> **And finally, the getter and setter methods are needed because its bad practice to expose an instance variable in a method (in this case "sign_in")?**

In my opinion, the getter and setter methods are not exactly needed. It is possible to just use `@current_user` throughout the helper.
However, [Devise (a popular user authentication gem)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) utilises the `current_user` method in its helpers. This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608598/the-use-of-self-current-user-in-ruby-on-rails-tutorial#comment22137740_15608635) is relevant as well.

---

> **In other words, it would be bad to replace: `self.current_user = user` with `@current_user = user` in the "sign_in" method?**

There should be nothing wrong with replacing it with `@current_user = user`. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15608598/559119) (same link as linked comment above) shows you that the functionality is identical in the case of the tutorial.